# Keycloak, Federation and custom roles

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot, keycloak, saml

Currently I'm working in a webapp based in Angular and Spring, we want to use Keycloak as centralized authentication which will connect to the companmy's Federation to authenticate users but we want to map the roles in the app database.
Would this be possible? so that Keycloak can autheticate the user against the Federation service, and then enhance the user details with the roles form our own DB doing a search by username/email.

Comment: Hi, i have the same question ! You fined a answer please ?

Comment: We aren't going that route as our roles requirements are too complex to be manged this way.
We found however that the Keycloak API allows some behaviours similar to this.
t is also possible to develop addons which can connect to external DBS so probably that can also help with enhacing the info.